# Yii: CListview sorting by a dynamic model attribute

Tags: php, sorting, yii, clistview

I have a CListview which displays a list of products. I need to sort that list using location of the product. Product model has method getDistance() which calculates the distance between user and the product. Is there an easy way to achive that using CSort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `CActiveDataProvider` as data provider in your `CListView` then you must calculate same distance value in SQL query (to be able to `compare` and sort). If this is complicated, you can switch to [CArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider). where you can do your complex calculations and set them to model attributes.